# New Android APK build updates not taking effect

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo, apk

I am having an issue with building apps for iOS and Android, and the matter is very time sensitive.

I have a React Native Expo app, and build new versions on a regular basis. I haven't experiences these issues before.

Just last week, I built a new APK for our staging environment, to test before building for production. I took the usual steps I take to build the apps, but the issue I am having, is the new APK I built for production, is actually using my staging credentials, and thinks the app is an older version.

The current version I am trying to build for is `1.8.4`, and I have incremented my `versionCode`. However, when launching the app, the Google sign in fails, because of a `redirect_uri_mismatch`, because it is using my staging credentials. The app also is showing version `1.8.0` (it is getting this number from my `app.config.js`), despite when inspecting the app info says it is version `1.8.4`.

I have deleted the `android` directory in my project, ran `npx expo prebuild` using my production credentials, and then checked the files including the `google-services.json` to ensure the right values were being used, and all is good. I then generate the APK through Android Studio with no issues, but then once installed, the apps updates are not in places.

I know this may not be enough to go off, but I am running out of time and lost.

Thanks

Comment: Did you uninstall the app from emulator/device?
Do you build local or with eas?

Comment: Yes I uninstalled the app from the devices before installing the new one. And I am not sure what you mean by ``local``, but I do not use EAS, I use ``npx expo prebuild``, then generate the signed APK/AAB in Android Studio.

Comment: With local I mean you build with ```npx eas build -p android --local```